# Convert minute of day into NSDate?

Tags: swift, date, nsdate

Good afternoon, I'm developing an app that uses an API that provides minute of the day instead of a straight forward date (for instance, "minute" : 23). How would I convert that to a date object of either 12:23AM or 00:23 (either one does not matter). I tried using TimeInterval but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: You can use `(NS)DateComponents` for that.

Comment: `NSDate`s only represent exact instants in time, not something abstract like "minute 23". As @Larme mentions, `NSDateComponents` can be used to represent that instead.

Comment: What is your actual goal? Do you want a number such as 690 to be converted into today's date at 11:30 am as a `Date` instance. Or do you want a number such as 690 to be converted to a string such as "11:30"? [Edit] your question to clearly explain what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

If your date is always referencing the current day, you could do something like this:

```
//minutes from API, hardcoded for example
let minute = 123

let calendar = Calendar.current
//Get the current year, month, and day as individual date components
var components = calendar.dateComponents([.calendar, .year, .month, .day], from: Date())

//Set minutes
components.minute = minute

//Get the full date.  As of today, resolves to "Jan 4, 2018 at 2:03 AM"
let date = components.date
```

Comment: @LeoDabus You are right - I didn't realize that.  I will edit.